# Ender 3 Pro extruder skipping and knocking, tried multiple things

Tags: creality-ender-3, pla, extruder, extrusion, print-failure

I recently purchased some MatterHackers Quantum PLA and began printing on my Ender 3 Pro. I successfully printed three times with no problem, on the fourth print about 2 hours in, the extruder started to skip and make knocking noises. The filament completely stopped extruding. I originally thought it was just a basic clog and I took steps to fix the problem:

1. I disassembled the print head and found a small bit of filament in the Bowden tube and cut the clogged piece off.
2. I cleaned out the heat sink and aluminum block of any debris
3. Replaced with a new nozzle
4. Tightened the spring on the extruder

I’ve checked the teeth on the extruder gear and they didn’t seem to be worn down

After all of this, I tried the same print again but printed at a nozzle temperature of 225 °C instead of the 215 °C I had it at originally, and it failed again near the same spot about 2 hours into the print.

Is there any advice I can get from anyone in the community as to why I’m having this problem?

Comment: Does another filament do this?

Comment: @DennisWilliamson no this was the first filament that it had happened on. Yesterday I tweaked the retraction settings and was able to successfully print the model with some stringing. I think the problem was mostly the model I was trying to print having far too many retractions in a certain stage of the print causing the filament to clog.

Comment: OK, I just wondered whether the filament had too much moisture.